# A continuous mapping $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ may have a fixed point?

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Let a function $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}， $satisfied  $$\forall x,y\in\mathbb{R},|f(x)-f(y)|\leq k|x-y|.(0<k<1)$$
Prove:
        There exists a only one $\xi\in \mathbb{R}$ ,such that $f(\xi)=\xi.$

---

***1st***    we can prove  $f\in C(-\infty,+\infty)$ ;

***2nd***   Let $g(x)=x-f(x)$,we can prove $g(x)$ is strictly monotonic on $（—\infty,+\infty）.$

***3rd*** If we can find ${x}_{1}, {x}_{2}\in\mathbb{R}$ and ${x}_{1}\ne {x}_{2},$such that $g({x}_{1})\leq 0,g({x}_{2})\geq 0.$then the conculsion will be proved.

---

But I failed to prove ***3rd***,sometimes I doubt the function $f$ may fail to have a fixed point in $\mathbb{R}$,I need a counterexample to comfirm my doubt.

- Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: I only know contraction mapping theorem and Cauchy convergence theorem and solve this easily. I don't know what you are writing.

Comment: You can't prove the third one because it doesn't necessarily happen. See the proofs of [Banach fixed point theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach_fixed-point_theorem#Proofs). And you still need to prove that there exists at most one fix point.

Comment: @GitGud: No, it's definitely true that there's only one fixpoint. It's even written in the WP page you link. For reference, assume $f(x) = x$ and $f(y) = y$, then $|x-y| = |f(x)-f(y)| \leq k |x-y| \implies x=y$ because $0 < k < 1$.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi I edited my comment, I got mixed up with something.

Comment: @Frankenstein It seems to me that $\lim_{x \to +\infty} g(x)=+\infty$ because $f$ grows at most like $kx$ and $k<1$.

Comment: @Troy Woo Maybe this easily for you ,but not for me .If you think seriously, you may find this quetion have a few small difference.

Comment: @Siminore  So what? my friend .Can you give me some further hints?

Answer (score 2):

You will not found any counter example.As it is a well known result that in a complete metric space any contraction map has a fixed point(Banach fixed point theorem).
As real number system R is complete so contraction map f has a fixed point.

Answer (score 1):

With $y=0$, the given inequality becomes $|f(x)-f(0)|\le k|x|$, i.e.,
$$ f(0)-k|x|<f(x)<f(0)+k|x|. $$
For $x>0$ you conclude $f(x)<f(0)+kx<x$ if $x$ is big enough.

Similarly, for $x<0$ you get $f(x)>f(0)+kx>x$ if $x$ is sufficiently negative.

Thus you have your point 3, and hence existence.

For uniqueness, assume $x$ and $y$ are fixed points and substitute them in the given inequality. (Or just use your point 2.)

**Addendum:** Some people refer to [Banach's fixed point theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach_fixed-point_theorem) for this. But as you can see, this much power is not needed in the simple case of a function $\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$. BTW, the argument in the previous paragraph also proves the (trivial) uniqueness part of Banach's theorem in the general case.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! you answer get the point that I want .